# Make parameter optional when type is never

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to write a function that given a route and an optional set of parameters returns the url with the placeholders in the route replaced with the given params.
The type of the params should match the placeholders in the route, if the route has no placeholders the params should be optional. Here's an example of the expected result:

```
type Route = '/no-placeholders' | '/path/:p1/:p2'

buildUrl('/unknown-route') // error, route does not exist
buildUrl('/no-placeholders', {}) // error, expected 1 param got 2
buildUrl('/no-placeholders')
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2') // error, expected 2 params, got 1
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2', { foo: '' }) // error, { foo: string } does not match { p1: string; p2: string }
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2', { p1: 'foo', p2: 'bar' })
```

So, what I've come out with is the following, the overloading is useless here, but I was trying to handle the case of `never` differently:

```
type PathParams<Path extends string> =
    Path extends `:${infer Param}/${infer Rest}` ? { [k in Param | keyof PathParams<Rest>]: string } :
    Path extends `:${infer Param}` ? { [k in Param]: string } :
    Path extends `${infer _Prefix}:${infer Rest}` ? { [k in keyof PathParams<`:${Rest}`>]: string } :
    never;

type Route = '/no-placeholders' | '/path/:p1/:p2'

function buildUrl<R extends Route>(route: R, params: never): string;
function buildUrl<R extends Route>(route: R, params: PathParams<R>): string;
function buildUrl(route: any, params: any) {
  // ...
  return route
}


buildUrl('/unknown-route') // expect error
buildUrl('/no-placeholders', {}) // expect error
buildUrl('/no-placeholders')
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2') // expect error
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2', { foo: '' }) // expect error
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2', { p1: 'foo', p2: 'bar' })
```

The problem is that `buildUrl` always require the second argument to be passed, even when the given route has no placeholders. Is there a way to make this second argument optional when `PathParams<R>` returns `never`?

---

**Solution**

Handle the routes without placeholders explicitly in the overload:

```
type RouteWithoutParams = '/no-placeholders'
type RouteWithParams = '/path/:p1/:p2'
type Route = RouteWithoutParams | RouteWithParams

function buildUrl<R extends RouteWithoutParams>(route: R): string;
function buildUrl<R extends Route>(route: R, params: PathParams<R>): string;
function buildUrl<R extends string>(route: R, params?: PathParams<R>) {
  // ...
  return route
}
```

Comment: I made an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle missing parameter, you need to explicitly mark it as optional:

```js
type PathParams<Path extends string> =
  Path extends `:${infer Param}/${infer Rest}` ? { [k in Param | keyof PathParams<Rest>]: string } :
  Path extends `:${infer Param}` ? { [k in Param]: string } :
  Path extends `${infer _Prefix}:${infer Rest}` ? { [k in keyof PathParams<`:${Rest}`>]: string } :
  never;

type Route = '/no-placeholders' | '/path/:p1/:p2'

function buildUrl<R extends '/no-placeholders'>(route: R): string;
function buildUrl<R extends Route>(route: R, params: PathParams<R>): string;
function buildUrl<R extends string>(route: R, params?: PathParams<R>) {
  // ...
  return route
}


buildUrl('/unknown-route') // error, route does not exist
buildUrl('/no-placeholders', {}) // error, expected 1 param got 2
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2') // error, expected 2 params, got 1
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2', { foo: '' }) // error, { foo: string } does not match { p1: string; p2: string }


buildUrl('/no-placeholders') // ok
buildUrl('/path/:p1/:p2', { p1: 'foo', p2: 'bar' }) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFvATnAtgZwDzyVCAD2AgDsATTKTYFAS1IHMA+KAXgCgpYFEDiylKAAMAXABIA3gwBmEFDzToAvgHops+VABKEGsuFQA-FElQA2gGsoDRRigAfKJYggA9jJ5JUGHLprMALqi1LQMjFDKUKJcXnxEJBRUYhqkcgo+KoYmZlY2pHbowaH0TJHRsXjxAkkiqelQAPowKBAydITKEtJpWv7ABsamFta2Lu6eVZk4KZL9BkEhNKURUTHcpBAAbvIA3BwcoJA6bgCuJOxQAOSqpG4AtGAANnAAxhCIbk-k8phXjtdVGBeKpRGAAIygsAAJiuBxkp1Ir2AdDcBQARqc6N8AKooJ7YbT8RJCG53R4vd6fb6-K7MAAUKDOJBC2gAlEswkx9gikSi0VBMdjyHiCUSEoIqNpmRAGUzzhBWQAaKDApSYEJTODqwnMDklcI8xHI1EYrG4-GE4mSg1MOUy5Wq7W+Iya3jTXVs0yxVSqKAAOkDsVawFOKAK8pIHGUBw4QotT3pN0RljuAHdSPdIxArl7fQQUEyUCrs1ByG49FA7sB+HQaHHzSL8Unbg9nm8Pl8fig-irJMo8375EWVURIMiIOQoOCnUooIw3DXoQ3haKW8CkFDIWDYYOCyP+OOSFPobPfCqFzXwSuE+uQWDtzCrn2oDI3G4Qld-gOoPnh25i2GN8P1tVYywrKhqygdAEFePgzAhTkVl2VVoSQ8JIljeMm0TMk20pTsaR7XNfz9NxLBvHC703B8oVhF9EOuYDn1Qz90W1b893IoA)

You need to explicitly define an overload rule for literal `'/no-placeholders'`

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense, I can split the routes in with&without params and handle the 2 cases in the overload. I didn't think about it, thank you! I'll try